# Create a new column based on another column's content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column called `returns_direction` based on contents of `returns` column. if `returns` are positive, 1 for `return_direction` or 0 otherwise.

Here is my code:

```
for i in df['returns']:
    if df['returns'][i] > 0:
        df['returns_direction'][i] == 1
    else:
        df['returns_direction'][i] == 0
    
df.head()
```

But what I got is a `KeyError: 0.0154199803149606`, how can I fix this?

Comment: `==` means `equal` not `assign`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misuse `i` in `for i in df['returns']:` as an index, it is assigned as the element value, such as the `0.0154199803149606` in your data.

If you need to use the corresponding index for `df['returns_direction']`:

```py
# Create new column first
df['returns_direction'] = 0

# Assign values
for i, v in enumerate(df['returns']):
    if v > 0:
        df['returns_direction'][i] = 1
    else:
        df['returns_direction'][i] = 0

# or concisely
for i, v in enumerate(df['returns']):
    df['returns_direction'][i] = (1 if v > 0 else 0)
```

Comment: thank you. I understood where went wrong.

Comment: i tries this one, but i got KeyError: 'returns_direction' Could you tell why this happened?

Comment: @claire What is the your current code? If the column `'returns_direction' ` does not exist before you do this assignment you need to create the column first, or the `KeyError` will raise.

Comment: oh i got it. i need to create a new empty column.